# Should I use an Isolation Relay between a Furnace and Humidifier?

Tags: relay

I recently installed a new Aprilaire 700 humidifier attached to a Carrier Infinity 96 furnace.  It has been working perfectly for the past 3 days.

Considering the fact that there are 2 distinct circuits connected via 24 VAC line, I was wondering if I should protect my furnace ($$$$) from the humidifier ($$) by inserting a SPNO isolation relay-switch that is energized by the furnace’s HUM-COM circuit and that which closes the normally-open switch on humidifier’s 24 volt line.

[image]

Comment: Wait. How are the 120V/240V circuits switched *now*?  Are you sure it isn't like this already?

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace + photos of the wiring?

Comment: 1) ThreePhaseEel: Silly Question:  How do I attach a wiring diagram.  I don't see it button/link anywhere on the page.

Comment: Harper:  I believe I understand the reason you are asking me the question.  I guess your reasoning goes as: the humidifier's fan running on 120V is triggered when HUM-COM (24 V) circuit between the Furnace and Humidifier is activated.  So, if this is the case (observed situation), then the 24V signal (Control) must be triggering the circuit-closure for the fan (120V) and solenoid (24 V).  Hence there must be a built-in SPNO isolation relay-switch inside the humidifier.  I'll open the humidifier tomorrow and check it out.  Thanks for your question.  It made me think in the correct way about it.

Comment: Harper:  I followed-up on your suggestion and checked the humidifier's internal.  Just as you thought/mentioned, there is a relay [Clion hhc68a-2a] inside the humidifier. I guess I am all set -no need for an isolation relay. Appreciate your help!!!